# Регулярное выражение - попадает два значения, но нужно только  второе

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Есть код:

```
<th>Действует по</th>
<th>Кто регил</th>
<th>Зарегистрирован на</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="centerColumn typeColumn">Репер</td>
<td class="centerColumn dateColumn">01-03-2014</td>
<td class="centerColumn dateColumn">28-02-2015</td>

<th>Действует по</th>
<th>Кто регил</th>
<th>Зарегистрирован на</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="centerColumn typeColumn">Репер</td>
<td class="centerColumn dateColumn">01-03-2013</td>
<td class="centerColumn dateColumn">28-12-2016</td>
```

Применяю регулярку `<th>Действует по<\/th>([^>]*>){14}`, но под нее попадает два значения,  а мне нужно второе (т.е. забрать дату во втором совпадении, а не в первом).

Comment: Язык программирования какой? И непонятно? какой второй, приведите пример.

Comment: javascript, там две группы у них начало одинаковое, но даты разные. если применять мою регулярку, то будет 28-02-2015, а мне нужно 28-12-2016

Comment: @mousesport, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Источник, ищем по фразе (как получить последнее вхождение в строке?)](http://javascript.ru/RegExp)

Код примера получения последнего вхождения:

```
var s = 'раз два три';
var res = s.match(/\S+/g);
var last_res = res[res.length - 1];
alert(last_res);
```

Думаю, смысл понятен. Обратите внимание на g.